# Trying to export const to another component in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to use the addItem const from my Products component and use it in the Header component.
I tried exporting it to the Header component but I must be doing something wrong. The addItem works fine in the  tag within my return statement in my Products component. Cannot get addItem to show in the anchor tag in Header component. Hope that makes sense :)

```
import React, {useState} from "react";

function Products(props)
{    
    const [addItem, setAddItem] = useState(0);
    function increaseCart(event){
    setAddItem(addItem + 1);
    }
    

return(
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div className ="products-container">
    <h1>{addItem}</h1>
        <img className="product-image" src ={props.image}></img>
        <div class="product-info">
        <h6>{props.product}</h6>
        <p className="product-price">{props.price}</p>
        
        <p>{props.description.substring(0,200)+"..."}</p> 
        <div className="buttons-container">
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-success btn-lg add-cart-btn product-btn" onClick={increaseCart}>Add to Cart</button>
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-success btn-lg more-details-btn product-btn">More details</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
)
}

export default Products;
export {addItem};


---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

import React from "react";
import {addItem} from "./Products";


function Header(){
  
    return(
        
            <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a className="navbar-brand" href="#"><img className="logo" src="images/vr-logo.svg"></img></a>
  <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul className="navbar-nav">
      <li className="nav-item active">
        <a className="nav-link" href="#">VR Headsets<span className="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li className="nav-item">
        <a className="nav-link" href="#">Graphics Cards</a>
      </li>
      <li className="nav-item">
        <a className="nav-link" href="#">Games</a>
      </li>
      <li className="nav-item">
      <img className ="nav-link cart" src ="images/supermarket.svg"></img>
      </li>
      <li className="nav-item">
      <a className="nav-link" href="#">{addItem}</a>
      </li>


      
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
 
    )

}

export default Header;
```

Comment: You need to move the `addItem` function up to the Header component and pass it into this component as a prop. Exporting with `export` is static; it's done when the script is first interpreted, however, the function does not exist until this component is rendered.

Comment: pass it as a `prop`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is something you can't export. In order to accomplish sharing properties from other components you would need to have it passed from the top down and/or back up again, or rely on a central state management system.

What you would need to do:

```
- App Component: [add, setAdd]
  - Header: passed from App
  - Products: passed from App
```

This is sometimes referred to as "Prop Drilling" which is to send props from the top level and pass it through each component that needs it. If you use a state management system, you could avoid this and could use something like (in order of complexity) React Context, Recoil (new), MobX, or Redux.

--

Click the **"Run code snippet"** below to see it in action:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Header = props => {
  return (<header style={{ lineHeight: '50px', display: 'block', width: 'calc(100% - 20px)', padding: '0 10px', height: '50px', background: '#efefef'}}>My App - Cart: {props.add || 0}</header>)
};

const Product = props => {
  const onClickButton = () => {
    props.setAdd(props.add + 1);
  }
  
  return (<div><h1>My Product</h1><button onClick={onClickButton}>Add</button></div>);
}

const App = () => {
  const [add, setAdd] = useState(0);
  
  return (<div>
    <Header add={add} />
     <Product add={add} setAdd={setAdd} />
  </div>);
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/babel" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The react way of doing this is to pass your `addItem` state to your `Header` component as a prop. That way React can know about in order to reflect the change in your state properly.

The easiest way of doing this is by declaring your `addItem` state on top of the React component tree, and then pass it as a prop to other components that may use it.

for example, say you have this component structure:

```
<Header/>
<Cart/>
<Products>
etc...
```

You can declare your state in the parent component that is holding your component structure so you can pass it as a prop as needed to other components.

```
<Header/>
<Cart addItem = { addItem }/>
<Products addItem = { addItem } setItem = { setItem }/>
```

You can also make your state globally accessible with [React context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Or by using a state management library like [Redux](https://redux.js.org/)